# JQuery / JSP form not submitting

Tags: jquery, jsp

I have an application based in the Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework.
I have this piece of code in my JSP, but when I click the button the form does not submit

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#confirmApplicationProcessButtonId').click(function(){
                    $('#deviceFormId').attr('method', 'post');
                    $('#deviceFormId').attr('action', '${contextPath}/device/submit');
                    $('#deviceFormId').submit();

                });
</script>


<form:form commandName="deviceForm"
                                                name="deviceForm"
                                                id="deviceFormId"
                                                method="get"
                                                action="${contextPath}/newdesign/applicant/device/${deviceForm.device.id}"                                              
                                                htmlEscape="yes"
                                                enctype="multipart/form-data">



<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"            id="confirmApplicationProcessButtonId"         disabled="disabled" ><fmt:message key="confirm.device.process" /></button>


</form:form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what Abdul Hameed said, the script where you attempt to bind the callback for click event is executed before the button element is added to the DOM, so it can't find an element with id "confirmApplicationProcessButtonId", and no binding is done. Just put the script after the button.

Answer (score 1):

remove the disable attribute for the button

Comment: While your answer might solve the problem, you should emphizise a bit more on WHY this solution works. In this case, for example, data is not submitted to the server, when the input control is completely disabled.